# Specific area of the app that JasmineJS needs to test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Hi guys I am new to Jasmine JS and am still a bit confused on what/which area of the application that Jasmine JS needs to test.

For example in your end you are creating a registration page for your application, what part of the registration feature you think you require Jasmine to test.

Thanks in advance and your different thoughts is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine tests your javascript files, that is the part of your app that you would need to test. A good test, will test your API. If we say that your app is a machine, the API would be the controls that operate your machine. If your app is a registration field, you would test that the inputs are processing the data properly. You would also want to consider what edge cases might interact with your code in an undesirable way. Such as a user inputing a number when you are requesting a string. You would also want to test these edge cases.